# Does the universe have an ultimate purpose?

Tags: epistemology, consciousness, existence, meaning, teleology

Objective purpose is an alternative? Universal, fundamental purpose?

Comment: Please add some background about what connects to this and what you expect to find out?

Comment: We do not know... Many philosophers speculated about this; see e.g. [Teleology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology) and [Divine Providence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/providence-divine/). Contra, see [Hope and Existentialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hope/#PostKantPhilExis).

Comment: @Corbin Is this an answer? If so, can you support your assertion?

Comment: @Meanach: It's like asking "does the universe have objective justice" or "does the universe exhibit objective beauty;" because purpose is a social construction, each person is free to define purpose in their own way, and there is no such thing as objective purpose.

Comment: @ Corbin. Why are you so sure?

Answer (score 1):

A purpose is something related to the one that "has" it. If I have a purpose it means that I pursue something or that I am made in order to do something. So the purpose is either a self realization or the goal of a creator. By taking the analogy to the universe (if we assume that a purpose exists) there seem to be two alternatives:

1. Someone (God) created the universe for a purpose.
2. The universe has an intrinsic realization of purpose, perhaps as an aggregation of the purposes of all living beings, or something like that.

I beleive - but it is just an instinct - that the way to find the purpose is by trying to make a reconciliation of both these views.